# javascript form with a popup

Tags: javascript, forms

Really basic, I'm just trying to understand how to test a form using simple JavaScript **without jQuery** etc.  Tried W3Schools but didn't work.
So I'm trying just a simple form instead with one field to get how it all works.  Below I put a single field in a form, and thought I could test the fname variable against the firstName field.

But what happens is that the alert is never hit in the if statement. How to test the field firstName?

Any tips would be helpful.

```js
function validateForm() {
  var fname = document.getElementById("firstName");
  if (fname == "") {
    alert("first name is a mandatory field");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("formMessage").innerHTML = fname + " entered.";
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Question 1 validate with alert popups</h2>

<p>Please enter the following mandatory information</p>

<form name="identification">
  <p>First Name:<input type="text" id="firstName" /></p>
  <p>
    <button type="button" onclick="validateForm()">Submit</button>
  </p>
</form>

<p id="formMessage"></p>
```

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById("firstName").value`

Comment: aha!  thanks that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing the element itself. You should instead check the `value` of the element.

e.g.

```
var fname = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

fname is the element when you do document.getElementById, so you have to do:

```
function validateForm() {
            var fname = document.getElementById("firstName");
                if (fname.value == "") {
                    alert("first name is a mandatory field");
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("formMessage").innerHTML = fname.value + " entered.";
                }
            }
```

You might also want to trim fname.value in case the user inputs bunch of empty spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("firstName").value` to get the value. if you don't add `.value` it means it didn't read the specified value.